# Problem with [NOMINATIVE] Case in GB & Phase Theory (MP)

Tags: cases, minimalism, government-and-binding

Most of works on case theory in generative syntax GB (Vergnaud, 1985; Chomsky, 1981, 1986, among others) and in MP (Chomsky, 1995, et seq; Gallego, 2010; Hornstein, 2011, among others) assume the following: [Nominative] Case is assigned:

1. In GB by a tensed head of IP (I=+tense) under government;
 2. In Phase Theory (Minimalist Syntax) by probing of T to value the {NOM} in Spec,*v**P.

I've never come across any assumption that a {nominative} case can be assigned by a lexical head Preposition (which, in most cases, assigns Oblique Case, and may be another type of case in other languages, but never Nominative). There are data, however, that show that a lexical head P assigns or 'values' in minimalist terms the {Nominative}: 

 (1)

y.ufa u.yaz a.ghrum 
find  NOM.man ACC.bread 
'The man.nom found a bread.acc'

In (1), there's no problem, because no preposition was added into the constructions. Imagine we add another PP phrase like 'on the road' as in (2): 
(2) 
y.ufa u.ayaz .a.ghrum ig u.brid 
 
find man.NOM bread.ACC on road.NOM 
'The man.nom found the bread.acc on the road.nom'

**a**: is the ACCUSATIVE MARKER 
**u**: is the NOMINATIVE MARKER 
**ig**: is a preposition meaning literally 'with' and translated as 'on'.

Is this something odd, or there're other languages that allow nominative assignment under P?

Comment: What language are your data from?

Comment: Berber (spoken in Northern Morocco)

Comment: @jknappen It is Riffian.

Comment: @Tsutsu T. it would be more interesting to bring up phrasal verb like "azzel x" (=run after) because the subject and the object have the same marker: yuzzel Uqzin x Ughyul = The dog chased the donkey.

Comment: @amegnunsen, there's also 'a-qzin yuzr x u-ghyur' which is not the same..forget about what 'I should bring' and 'what I should not', this is not the thing we are after here.. most of accounts I came across are grounded within templatic analyses (phon), Berber phonologists seem to be enslaved by these templates, but close scrutiny reveal their feficiency. In generative syntax, descriptive adequacy is not enough, there must be accounts, why is the 'marker' extended to a PP, abarnert said something below about 'fusion' which might be something to start with. This would be an account..

Comment: @tsutsu t. I don't know about what you are looking for, but phonology without prosody (because you are interested in utterances) and phonetic (because you need it to describe the prosody) is meaningless.

Comment: @amegnunsen praising your field of study as if I said there's no phonology or I denied the existence of utterances or phonetics. You don't know what I'm looking for because you study phonology, not syntax. If you're familiar with the references I mentioned above (orginal post), you will understand the issue.

Comment: @tsutsu t. I am not acquainted with generative syntax, but it doesn't mean I am completely ignorant in syntax. That reminds me to tell you that the head of PP is a preposition, not a noun. So there is not assigned marker for a PP. That is why I advise you to take into account phrasal verb -maybe I shouldn't- instead of PP.

Comment: The preposition is a head of Prepositional Phrase with an NP complement headed by a lexical N. Noun Phrases are assumed to get case marked by lexical heads (in this case a P). For example, accusative case is assigned by a P in infinitival clauses like 'for him to love the job would be great', they do so too in relation to finite clauses 'she leaned towards him', the oblique case is assigned also by P. Saying that in a PP there's no case assigned is as surface as saying that CS proceeds according to some templatic analysis and stop there! there's more to that, if you read syntactic accounts.

Comment: When I said that templatic analysis of CS or Case in terms of morphophonological accounts is limited, I didn't mean that there's no phonological account of the free vs construct state marking, what I meant is that it's not as deep as the requirement or expectation from an explanatory adequacy in minimalist syntax would meet. Yes, they're descriptive in Guerssel, Lahrouchi, Boukhris, Sadiqi, Benjaballah, El Moujahid, Ridouane, among many others, but they according to syntactic accounts (Phase Theory to be precise) they're not even explanatory, only descriptive. Where PT expects it beyond.

Comment: @tsutsu t. Before going beyond, you should be sure there is a system of case markers in Riffian and should we consider annexed state as a case marker. Because, in my humble opinion, annexed state is not a marker for morphosyntactic alignment. Annexed state is another declension noun that can be combined with a case marker: Case marker + Annexed state + Noun. When a noun is subject, it is encoded: nothing + u + noun, when it is an object: nothing + a + noun, and when it is an indirect object: dative case + u + noun.

Comment: @amegnunsen as I told you the primitive descriptive accounts you mentioned are all scattered in the writings of the authors I referred to in my last comment, but the discussion is pushed further in minimalist accounts (see Ouali, 2011). But thank you for your contribution in this discussion :)

Comment: @tsutsu t. Maybe there is a misunderstanding. You consider as established the fact that case markers are real linguistic facts in Riffian and the morpheme "u" and "a" are categorised in such way. But no one among the authors you cited has demonstrated the relevance of using this terminology. They use it only by blind conformity not all that much. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The short, oversimplified answer is that Berber languages merge their "oblique" and "nominative" in much the same way that English merges its "oblique" and "accusative". Plenty of other languages do something similar, like most of the Northwest Caucasian languages. There's nothing magical about oblique and accusative that forces them to be merged when coming up with a two-overt-case system.

---

From a quick search, as I understand it, Berber is at least sometimes considered ergative-absolutive, not nominative-accusative, or at least more like E-A than N-A. While it doesn't match the facts of, e.g., Basque exactly, simple constructions give one case ("ergative") to transitive subjects, and the other ("absolutive") to both objects and intransitive subjects. And the objects of most prepositions get the "ergative" case. (There are even analyses that insist that Berber's "cases" aren't even really cases, although that seems to be a minority view.)

At any rate, however you analyze the "subject case" in Berber, the one that occurs on the subject of most simple transitive sentences, there's no reason that can't be the same as other cases. English assigning what looks like accusative case to the objects of most prepositions is hardly universal. Whether you prefer to describe English as having created an objective case that subsumed accusative, dative, and oblique, or as having merged accusative and dative into oblique, that's not the only way to get to a two-case system. And patterning transitive subjects with objects of (some) prepositions is one of the many other ways, attested in multiple languages (although mostly E-A languages).

Finally, I don't think Berber is usually analyzed as having case *prefixes*. Your "a-" and "u-" prefixes only work for the first class of nouns; you can't describe the other classes ("tarbat/terbat", "iles/yiles", and "taddart/taddart") with the same prefixes. What you called the "accusative" is considered the base form ("free state"), and the nominative or ergative or whatever ("construct state") is described as formed by vowel alternation rules (different ones for each class).

Exactly how you handle all of that in Case theory depends on how you handle ergative languages and how you handle case mergers. A system that can't handle anything but English just won't work for Berber languages. Obviously a system that always assigns NOM to the subject position won't work for ergative languages unless there's a second layer than can then map NOM to ergative in transitive sentences and absolutive in intransitive sentences. But a system that can assign ERG in some languages and NOM in others, or that moves subjects to different locations (one ERG-assigning, one NOM-assigning) in different languages, doesn't need that. Whatever you do there, you can do a simpler version of for prepositions assigning case in various different languages. It's impossible to answer for all of the Case theories proposed for every version of GB and MP, but should be easy for any specific theory.

Comment: Usually considered? Who are these persons? Berber traditional linguists generally don't analyze these markers in term of grammatical case. Those that doing that use as description nominative-accusative. See: https://inslav.ru/images/stories/people/arkadiev/Arkadiev_2015_BerberStateLT.pdf

Comment: @amegnunsen Skimming the paper you linked (I'll go back and read it more carefully), it seems to say the opposite of what you're saying: The traditional distinction is of "state" between "absolute" and "annexed", but the idea that these can't be mapped to case is a recent and interesting proposal that this paper is rejecting. The paper then argues that Berber can be handled the same as all languages in terms of universal Case theory, and that it patterns with ergative-alignment languages in at least some ways.

Comment: @amegnunsen If you have a good (non-paywalled) survey article, that would be very helpful. I haven't found one in a quick search (and Wikipedia's article doesn't provide any sources).

Comment: Absolute here doesn't refer to a grammatical case. It means simply not marked or free state. Berber varieties don't belong to ergative languages. The subject of transitive verb is marked in similar way that the subject of an intransitive verb. You can formulate that it belongs to nominative-absolutive languages.

Comment: @amegnunsen I'm not equating "absolute state" with "absolutive case", I'm saying that the article is arguing that the state marking can be analyzed as case, and implying that (contra the recent article the authors are applying to) they usually are, while you said people don't usually do that. Again, without some kind of survey article or textbook, I can't really do more than try to infer from a handful of articles I found (plus the one you pointed out) and Wikipedia, which is why I used so much hedge-wording. ("From what I can gather", "I don't think", etc.)

Comment: @amegnunsen More to the point: If you think Berber has a "nominative case" and an "accusative case" with distinct suffixes and assimilates the preposition-marked ("oblique") to the former, as the OP seems to, then there's no point trying to repair my answer; it's just wrong, and you should write your own.

Comment: @amegnunsen Ack, I meant "prefixes", obviously. But anyway, if you have suggestions for how to improve my answer, tell me what they are; if you think my answer is just wrong, write a different answer. As it stands, I can't tell which you're doing.

Comment: I can't write down an answer because I don't know anything about the theoretical framework whose he speaks. Moreover, as far as I know, morphosyntactic alignment concerns only core arguments, but as for him, he has integrated in his thoughts PP.

Comment: @abarnert how is the nominative valued in Basque? if you have an idea.

Comment: @amegnunsen the framework is phase theory (generative syntax), chomsky (2001, 2008)